# Handled Orchard exception still bubbling up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, orchardcms

In my custom Orchard module I have written some ftp client code within a controller action that happens to throw a custom FtpException during login. I've wrapped the Login code in a try-catch and am sending a notification message back to the view if there's an error. The problem is that the error is still bubbling up and showing the standard "Oops. Something went wrong ... sorry" Orchard error message. Here's the code I am wrapping:

```
        try
        {
            ftpClient.Login();
            ftpClient.Upload(fileName);
        }
        catch (FtpException ex)
        {
            services.Notifier.Error(T("There was an error sending the file - {0}.", ex.Message));
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Project");
        }
        finally
        {
            ftpClient.Close();
        }

        services.Notifier.Information(T("File uploaded successfully."));
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Project");
```

If I look in the Orchard logs, I see that an FTP exception is thrown, from within `ftpClient.Login()`. The code in the catch block is executed, so I know that the exception has been handled. Trouble is, the unhandled exception behaviour is still being displayed by Orchard. How can I stop the exception from bubbling up so that my RedirectToAction will fire?

Comment: Is the exception being thrown definitely an FtpException (or derived type)?

Comment: It is, but to make sure, I changed the catch block to catch System.Exception - result was the same

Comment: Ok, have you tried stepping through to see what happens when the exception is called? Could it be possible that an exception is being thrown by ftpClient.Login, it is caught by your catch, and then *another* exception is being generated by the finally trying to close the already closed ftpClient?

Comment: Ah - that could be the issue - hard to tell though as this code works locally and only falls over once it gets inside Azure. The Orchard logs highlight the error as being in the Login call rather than the Close call though. Will trying juggling the finally block and report back - thanks

Comment: Awesome - that is exactly the problem. There's another exception thrown in the finally block - if you would be kind enough to turn that into an answer...

Comment: Done, glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it is possible that the following is happening:

1. Execution enters the `try`, and gets to the call to `Login()`, and throws an exception.
2. Execution jumps to your catch block, which attempts to call `Close()` on your `ftpClient` object.
3. I'm unsure of the exact type of `ftpClient`, but it makes sense that calling `Close()` on an instance that may not have necessarily been opened (via `Login` in the first place) would throw another exception, and it is that which is being caught by Orchard's exception handler.

I'd start by looking for (or adding) some kind of `IsOpen` property to the FTP client class, or by wrapping the `Login` call in a separate try/catch so you can distinguish between a failure to login and another failure. Or if you have access to the source, you could get `Login` to throw a different type of exception if it fails.